# Scope of extern variable outside directory

Tags: c, extern

I am trying to use a variable whose value is set to 1 after a a option is passed to a code.

`MyValueis =1` in a code say `/abc/xyz/abc.c`

Means a c code check that a particular option is passed to it.If it is true, it set the value of variable to 1.Now if the value of variable is set to 1, i need to enable a different code in a different directory but within same sofwarw code.

So i declared the variable as extern

```
extern int MyValueis;
```

is this extern variable is accessible in a different directory inside same software code?

I had read certain articles regarding scope of extern variable but they don't proved to be useful in my question.

Comment: Have you heard of the compiler? Object code? Executables?

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try? How it didn't work?

Comment: @user694733 - Please give yourself a handle - Will put you apart from the others trying to get us doing their homework.

Comment: @EdHeal But I love my perfectly unique name. :)

Comment: @user694733 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner and George Orwell

Answer (score 0):

Source code directory doesn't matter in C. What matters is source code file and executables (programs).

If the object code file `abc.o` is linked with your other code, then the variable will be available in the other code no matter which directory the source code happen to be in.